# Change default option on dual boot screen

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, grub, multi-boot

I want to know how I can change the default selected option on the GNU GRUB dual boot screen displayed on system start-up.

I have a Windows 7 and Ubuntu dual boot PC. Currently there is a countdown timer that auto boots into Ubuntu if the time runs out. This is quite annoying since I use Ubuntu seldom.

I do not want to select Windows 7 every time. How can I change the default to Windows 7? See image below of dual boot screen.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fire up a terminal and first type:

```
 fgrep menuentry /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

This lists all the bootable operating systems on your machine. Now copy the entry you want to be default  which is in your case `Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)`. Note I have assumed it is the sda1 partition, if not please copy `Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda2)`. Copying in the terminal can be done by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Now, type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Now, find the line which says `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` and replace it with `GRUB_DEFAULT=Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)` or `/sda2` if that is the case.

Close gedit and come back to the terminal and type:

```
sudo update-grub
```

That's it!

**Note: The reason I gave such a long answer in contrast to `davidgo`'s shorter answer is that when you do kernel updates, you'll have those older kernel versions in the lines below so X=5 might mean Windows now but some Ubuntu version later. This ensures no more tinkering even with kernel updates.**

[Source](http://www.joewein.net/blog/2009/11/28/fix-windows-as-default-boot-on-ubuntu-9-10-with-grub2-loader/)

Comment: Might be worth adding that `GRUB_DEFAULT=Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)` may require single quotes around the value e.g. `GRUB_DEFAULT='Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)'`

Answer (score 1):

Under Linux, edit /boot/grub/menu.lst and add / change the line which says "default X"  - where X is the option you want to boot by default, so at a guess, X=5 or 6 for you.

Alternatively you can reorder the blocks in this file so the Windows one you want is first in the list.